# Adding variable into animate css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am having a problem knowing how to correctly write these variables and then placing them into `animate`.

```
var findCanvasMarginTop = ((100vh - 120) - cvsH) / 2;
var newCanvasMargin = findCanvasMarginTop + "px", 0, 0, 0;
var deployCanvasMargin = {'margin' : newCanvasMargin};
$('#text__menu--show').click(function () {
    $('#canvas__container').animate(deployCanvasMargin, 100);
});
```

Whenever I do this or variations of this my code fails to load.

I am finding the the margin between an element on my page and the top of the window.

Then I am creating the margins adding in the margin I found in the first variable and setting the other 3 margins to 0 (as the only margin required to change is the top margin).

Then I am creating deployCanvasMargin which is the css, then in `animate` I add in the variable.

I thought this would effectively make the outcome of `animate` this:

```
 $('#canvas__container').animate({'margin' : 50px, 0, 0, 0}, 100);
```

(Assuming 50px is the margin found)

**Edit:** I found another issue after the answer here helped me fix my `animate` issue. You can't have 100vh in the math. I need to create a variable that finds the viewport height and use that, not the css 100vh. Silly me :)

For anyone who has this same issue and is pretty inexperienced like me, I solved that additional issue by doing this

```
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)
```

Then changing the first variable to this

```
var findCanvasMarginTop = ((h - 120) - cvsH) / 2;
```

Comment: `{'margin' : 50px, 0, 0, 0}` is not valid JS

Answer (score 1):

jquery animate has following format

```
$(selector).animate({style}, 100);
```

means

```
$(selector).animate({margin : '10px'}, 100);
```

but you are passing object to animate.

instead use..

```
 $('#canvas__container').animate({margin : newCanvasMargin}, 100);
```

You cannot use `margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px` at once instead divide it into animation frame and use `margin-left` then `margin-right` ..

Answer (score 1):

`{'margin' : 50px, 0, 0, 0}` is not valid JS.

`var newCanvasMargin = findCanvasMarginTop, 0, 0, 0;` is not valid JS either.

Instead what you want to do is this:

```
var findCanvasMarginTop = ((100vh - 120) - cvsH) / 2;
var newCanvasMargin = findCanvasMarginTop + "px";
var deployCanvasMargin = {'margin-top' : newCanvasMargin};
$('#text__menu--show').click(function () {
    $('#canvas__container').animate(deployCanvasMargin, 100);
});
```